# Flutter firebase: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error:

> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

with the following code:

```
static List<Report?> reportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map<Report?>((report) {
      return Report(
        type: report['type'],
        reason: report['reason'],
        reportId: report['id'],
        chat:
            (report['chat'] == null) ? null : Chat.chatFromMap(report['chat']),
        stingray: Stingray.stingrayFromDynamic(report['stingray']),
        reporterUser: User.fromDynamic(report['reporterUser']),
        reportTime: report['reportTime'].toDate(),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Its failing on the first map,

```
type: report['type'],
```

and when i look at it in debug mode, it shows the data i am looking for:
[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, 'type' exists with a value of 'chat report'. Any idea why this is breaking?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is failing, that red dot in front of 72 (line 72) is a `breakpoint`. It pauses the code at that point. Click on that red dot to remove the `breakpoint`.

Comment: I did that, it progressed but will break after trying to read the snapshot.

Comment: Can you post the full error message, in the error message, the field causing the problem should be listed there. And confirm that the error message is not coming from inside this function `Chat.chatFromMap`

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem. You are supposed to call `.data()`. You didn't call it. I will post a solution in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be larger in scope than i thought. I was uploading a map object to firebase rather than just a document, and that map was attempting to be read, which is where the error occurred due to it only having one value in the document snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to call .data() on `report`

```
static List<Report> reportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  final List<Report> reports = [];
  for (final doc in snapshot.docs) {
    final report = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?; // you missed this line.
    if (report == null) continue;
    reports.push(
      Report(
        type: report['type'] as String,
        reason: report['reason'] as String,
        reportId: report['id'] as String,
        chat: (report['chat'] == null)
            ? null
            : Chat.chatFromMap(report['chat']),
        stingray: Stingray.stingrayFromDynamic(report['stingray']),
        reporterUser: User.fromDynamic(report['reporterUser']),
        reportTime: (report['reportTime'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      ),
    );
  }
  return reports;
}
// I returned List<Report> not List<Report?>
```

Check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) on how to use `withConverter` so you do not have to manually convert models.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have typo in your ***field*** which does not match with your ***model*** fields. So the idea is that, your fields in your model has to match with the fields in your firebase snapshot fields.
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/EbkHCF5jMTI)